# I am trying to create a feature in my plugin that selects start date and end date with an amount for a room

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

```
$query_charge = "select
        SUM(DATEDIFF(
            case when '2020-06-16' > `charge_from` then '2020-06-16' else `charge_from` end,
            case when '2020-06-28' < `charge_to` then '2020-06-28' else `charge_to` end) * `room_adv_cost`)
       from
       `$table`
       where
       `room_id` = '8289' AND
       `charge_to` >= '2020-06-16' and
       `charge_from` <= '2020-06-28'
      ";

        $val = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare($query_charge) );
```

The feature is like changing the room cost base on season. When I try the query in phpMyAdmin I get a result in negative, but when I use the same query on Wordpress in returns either null or 0.

Comment: I am not sure, but `CASE` is weird with NULL values. Did you try to replace with `IF`?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Also, you might like to familiarise yourself with GREATEST and LEAST